# How to search addresses in MKMap using MKLocalSearch

Tags: search, mkmapview, uisearchdisplaycontroller, mklocalsearch

I'm trying to search through the addresses using MKLocalSearch, but it only comes up with business and not the exact address like e.g Maps (Apple's App).

I hope u guys can help me out - thanks! :)

```
MKLocalSearchRequest *request = [[MKLocalSearchRequest alloc] init];
request.naturalLanguageQuery = query;
request.region = self.mapView.region;

[UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = YES;
self.localSearch = [[MKLocalSearch alloc] initWithRequest:request];

[self.localSearch startWithCompletionHandler:^(MKLocalSearchResponse *response, NSError *error){

    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;

    if (error != nil) {
        [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Map Error"
                                    message:[error description]
                                   delegate:nil
                          cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                          otherButtonTitles:nil] show];
        return;
    }

    self.results = response;
```

`

Answer (score 0):

In your results array, which is of type MKMapItem you need to configure the cells to give you the address when the tableView presents itself. Here's a quick example.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let IDENTIFIER = "CellID"
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(IDENTIFIER, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell

    // Configure the cell...
    var item: MKMapItem = results[indexPath.row]

    cell.textLabel?.text = item.placemark.name
    cell.detailTextLabel?.text = item.placemark.addressDictionary["Street"] as? String

    return cell
}
```

This is all done in your cellForRowAtIndexPath method that belongs to the UITableViewDataSource protocol.

Hope that helps, and best of luck to you!